# What is the difference between X.509 certificate and WTLS certificate

Tags: x509

I would like to know the difference between these two certificates and which one is useful in wireless communication environment.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't actually know anything about WTLS but I do know about wikipedia and wikipedia [tells us that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Transport_Layer_Security)

1) WTLS certificates are based on x509 but designed to be more compact... which is generally a considered to be a good goal for mobile devices

2) WTLS is a part of the WAP stack... which is generally considered to be a dead technology

So putting this all together... if you are working with a WAP stack for some reason, it sucks to be you but hey, at least now you have a good reason for learning more about WTLS.  If you aren't working with WAP, congratulations on being like 99% of everything else being built these days and also for getting to ignore WTLS in favor of more traditional things like SSL.